# Package minted and tcolorbox produces LaTeX Error: Command \gather already defined

Tags: tcolorbox, minted

After the massive update of the Miktex distribution, I have observed the collision between the `minted` package and `tcolorbox`. Interestingly, the compilation runs successfully if I remove the option **most** of the tcolorbox library. In other case I have seen the Latex error message:

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \gather already defined.
```

MNWE:

```
\listfiles
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{minted} 
\show\gather  
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\show\gather

\begin{document}
  Test
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because of package `lineno`. The current version *patches* environment `gather` even, if it has not been defined before. So `amsmath` cannot be loaded after `lineno` any longer. So, because `tcolorbox` with option `most` loads `amsmath`, you should load `minted` (which loads `lineno`) *after* `tcolorbox`:

```
\listfiles
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{minted} 

\begin{document}
  Test
\end{document}
```

And because current version of `tcolorbox` also has a module `minted`, I would suggest to use:

```
\listfiles
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[most,minted]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
  Test
\end{document}
```

Comment: https://github.com/latex-lineno/lineno/issues/5

Answer (score 3):

Because of package dependencies, it might not be obvious which package loads what. Using **\RequirePackage** might be a safer option as it ensures **amsmath** is always loaded first.

```
\RequirePackage{amsmath}
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{minted}   
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
  Test
\end{document}
```

Comment: very good idea :) thank yo

Comment: Loading `amsmath` before the class is IMHO not a documented feature of the package and could fail, if the class defines environments or commands, that have to be redefined by `amsmath`. Generally only some packages can be loaded before `\documentclass` others fail. I would not recommend to do so.